# Issue with background color of an image inside a button SwiftUi

Tags: button, swiftui

image inside the button appears blue. I cant figure out how to fix it.

```
Button(action: {self.count += 1}) {
    Circle()
        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("linkAccount1"), Color("linkAccount2")]), startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.2), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 1)))
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        .shadow(color: Color("shadowColor1"), radius: 7, y: 7)
        .overlay(
            //issue with image backgroud or foregroundColor
            Image("linkAccount")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60))
}
```

> Solution:
>   Image("linkAcount").renderingMode(.original)

Comment: Try `Image("linkAcount").renderingMode(.original)` this should remove the tint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, the issue is caused by the rendering mode of the Image.

You can overcome the tinting problem by using the `.renderingMode()` modifier, and setting the mode to be `.original`. This tells the image to ignore the tint.

```
 Image("linkAcount").renderingMode(.original)
```

Answer (score 0):

Images and Text contained within a button get rendred in accent colour, which by default is blue, just apply:

.accentColor(.white)

to your Button to have the image drawn in white.